# pull access denied for docker.wso2.com/wso2am

Tags: docker, wso2

I logged in successfully in docker.wso2.com registry and I am trying to pull docker.wso2.com/wso2am but it gives me the following error.

```
Error response from daemon: pull access denied for docker.wso2.com/wso2am, repository does not exist or may require 'docker login': denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Answer (score 0):

Your trial/subscription might have expired. You may [contact WSO2](https://support.wso2.com) directly to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

By default, **WSO2 API Manager** needs a **WSO2** subscription to pull from `docker.wso2.com`.

If you don't have a subscription you can pull from the open-source image instead :

```
docker pull wso2/wso2am
```